# How to communicate between two docker containers (mssql and .net core app)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following issue:  I have the following docker-compose file

```html
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        links:
            - my-special-db
        networks:
            - demo-net
    my-special-db:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer"
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - sa_password=demo
        networks:
            - demo-net
networks:
        demo-net:
          driver: nat
```

In the appsettings.Docker.json I have the following connection string: "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=my-special-db;Database=ContosoUniversity3;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" }

I've tried passing also the password, it doesn't work. 
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the statements and error you're getting when you try to connect.

Comment: Please repaste the YAML and JSON files as code blocks as well (with four leading spaces in the SO editor).  Indentation matters!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add both services in a common network.

Please rede this document: [Docker Networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/#scope-of-this-topic)

In each of your services:

```
  networks:
   - sql-net
```

In the end of the compose file:

```
networks:
   sql-net:
     driver: bridge
```

Then you'll be able to connect to the database through its container name, in your case `my-special-db`

## EDIT 1 - Network Drivers under windows

The error reported by the OP suggests that it's running Windows 10. There is an open bug for it [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1960)

There are reports that using `transparent`driver might work:

```
networks:
   sql-net:
     driver: transparent
```

## EDIT 2 - Links Option

You can also try using the legacy [Link feature](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). Add this to the `web` container:

```
web:
  links:
    - my-special-db
```

Comment: I've just tried and I get the following error : ERROR: could not find plugin bridge in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found

Comment: I'm trying with NAT driver but I have the same problem with db connectivity

Comment: Are you running Docker under windows 10? You're up to troubles. See: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1960

Comment: If you're using Windows 10, try setting `driver: transparent` . There are reports that it can work.

Comment: If not, you can try using the Network [Links legacy feature](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) to have inter container communication.

Comment: Transparent driver doesn't allow port forwarding. I've removed it from my docker-compose this part, but the problem persists, unfortunately.  Yes, I have the latest Win 10 Fall Update

Comment: Please confirm the Operating System you're using and also try the 3d option in the answer (Links)

Comment: I've edited the initial post with the links option. I confirm that I run Win 10 Fall Update (1809) with latest stable Docker version (2.0)